# Not able to open .svg files: XML parse error

Tags: svg

Upgraded to 20.04 today and, somehow, Document Viewer is not able to open `.svg` files. It keeps giving this error. Previously, when I was using 18.04, everything was working fine. No such errors I encountered.

```
XML parse error: error code=201 (3) in (null):606:15: Namespace prefix xlink for href on image is not defined
```

**EDIT**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <image id="image0" width="200" height="200" x="0" y="0"
    xlink:href="data:image/png;base64
```

Comment: try opening it in browser, browser also renders .svg file

Comment: yes or inkscape or so, but that does not fix the problem ;-)

Comment: Alternativelly, with version 2.0, you can use `href`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/href

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your  document viewer complains about the `svg` file having an `xlink` notation somewhere without being declared. As such, your `svg` file is not a valid `xml` and the document viewer complains correctly. Maybe in the newer version it is more strict about it.

To fix your file open it with an editor and make sure the `xlink` declaration is included in the `<svg>` tag in the very beginning of your file, it should look something like this:

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

---

**Update**: For your file, change this line:

```xml
<svg width="200" height="200">
```

to this:

```xml
<svg width="200" height="200"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

Comment: Alternatively, for SVG 2.0, you don't need any of that, and can use the `href` attribute directly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/href

Answer (score 4):

See: [<svg> - SVG: Scalable Vector Graphics | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg)

> The `svg` element is a container that defines a new coordinate system and viewport. It is used as the outermost element of SVG documents, but it can also be used to embed a SVG fragment inside an SVG or HTML document.
>
> **Note:** The `xmlns` attribute is only *required* on the outermost svg element of SVG documents. It is unnecessary for inner svg elements or inside HTML documents.

---

It is enough in most cases the `svg` tag to have the following attributes: `xmlns` and `viewBox`; optionally `width` and `height`:

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="50" height="50">
  <g>
    <path d=". . ."></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```